# How to flag outgoing email messages with a language

Tags: email, email-template

Our call center uses the service cloud and is paid per sent email. The price depends on the language of the email. To get the most accurate bills, we have to somehow flag all sent emails with the language of the email. I don't really know how this could be done and would appriciate any help.

Emails are sent using the standard "Send an Email" button on the email related list on cases. On the "Send an Email" screen, agents select a template, sometimes motify the text and send the email. They do not use the service console.

Is it possible to use some Javascript hack to get the template name? When we have the language in all template names (e. g. ..._FR, ..._EN), this could be used to set a custom language field on the email message.

I want to avoid a solution where agents would have to select the language automatically because mistakes and deliberately wrong declarations would be possible and this would cause more effort for each email. But if a manual solution is necessary, how could it be done in a convinient way for agents that send dozens or hundreds of emails per day?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there is no way to set manually the lenguaje when you are sending an email with the standard send email functionality, and it you probably will have to make a visualforce or component to achieve your requirements.

**Anyway I found some resource that could help you:**

[Translating emails using translation workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BKsYIAW)

[Visualforce templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/VisualForceEmailTemplates_sample) supports email template translation: [messaging:emailTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messaging_emailTemplate.htm).

> **Translated Template Example**
>
> ```
> <!-- This example requires that Label Workbench is enabled and that you have created
> the referenced labels. The example assumes that the Contact object has a custom language field that contains a valid language key. -->
>
> <messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact"
>   relatedToType="Account"
>   language="{!recipient.language__c}"
>   subject="{!$Label.email_subject}"
>   replyTo="cases@acme.nomail.com" >
>
>   <messaging:htmlEmailBody >        
>   <html>
>       <body>
>       <p>{!$Label.email_greeting} {!recipient.name}--</p>
>       <p>{!$Label.email_body}</p>
>       </body>
>   </html>
>   </messaging:htmlEmailBody> 
>
>    </messaging:emailTemplate>
> ```